# DatePicker setMinDate only works first time

Tags: java, android, android-studio, datepicker

My datepickerdialog works the first time regarding setting up the min date. But when I update it and click on it again, the setMinDate does not work. Here is my code:

```
if (duedateyear == 0) {
                final Calendar duecalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                duedateyear = duecalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                duedatemonth = duecalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                duedateday = duecalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            }

            DatePickerDialog duedatePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(Editor_Activity.this,
                    (datePicker, dueyear, duemonth, duedayOfMonth) -> {

                        String dueDate;

                        dueDate = duedayOfMonth + "/" + (duemonth + 1) + "/" + (dueyear);
                        dueDateStringfromCalendar = dueDate;


                    }, duedateyear, duedatemonth, duedateday);

            duedatePickerDialog.setOnCancelListener(dialog -> {
                dueDate = duedateday + "/" + (duedatemonth + 1) + "/" + (duedateyear);
                dueDateStringfromCalendar = dueDate;
            });
            duedatePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis());
            Log.d("EditorActivity", "Minimum Date Set");
            duedatePickerDialog.setTitle("");
            duedatePickerDialog.show();
            break;
```

For whatever, reason, the minimum Date Set does not work the second time or other times I update. Any help would be great.

Comment: You always set today as min date `setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis())`. What exactly does not work?

Comment: So when I open the datepicker dialog a second time, there is no minimum date. I can pick dates from last year, which I don't want to happen. Does that make sense?